# Accessing object used in some() function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I wrote this function to combine duplicate objects and add their quantities.

I'm having issues making the quantities add.

```
function removeDuplicates (input){

  var new_array = [];

  input.forEach(function(unmerged){
      if(new_array.some(item => item.model === unmerged.model)){
          item.quantity += unmerged.quantity; ////this throws error
      } else {
          new_array.push(unmerged);
      }
  });

  return new_array;
};
```

I assume that "item" is only created and used inside the some() function and no longer accessible. How can I fix this function such that I can edit its properties?

Ex:

before function:

```
var product_array = [
    {model:1, quantity:3},
    {model:1, quantity:2},
    {model:2, quantity:1}
];
```

after function:

```
var product_array = [
    {model:1, quantity:5},
    {model:2, quantity:1}
]
```

Comment: Can you add before/after examples of your arrays?

Comment: @Andy Just added an example.

Comment: `item` is not defined outside of `.some()` . What is purpose of adding `quantity` of same `item` to itself ? What is expected result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, item will only be accessible inside the arrow function scope.

You can use underscore (or lodash) .find function for it.

For example:

```
var item = _.find(new_array, {model : unmerged.model});
if (item) { 
    item.quantity += unmerged.quantity; 
}
```

You can also use es6 new array functions for it

```
var item = new_array.find(elem => elem.model ===unmerged.model);
```

Comment: the second option works beautifully, the lodash version doesn't   seem to for some reason.

Comment: Even better pattern is a reducer.

Comment: I've tried the first option with lodash and it works perfectly for me, are you sure you've added lodash to your project? anyway, if you are using es6 I will recommend the second option, the first one is just the easy way doing it in es5.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign *item* to a variable that *is* in scope and use that:

```
input.forEach(function(unmerged){
  var current; 
  if(new_array.some(item => {current = item; return item.model === unmerged.model})){
    current.quantity += unmerged.quantity; ////this throws error
  } else {
    new_array.push(unmerged);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For ES5, this is not the most elegant solution, but you can do it like this:

```
function comparator(obj1, obj2) {
  if (obj1.model < obj2.model) return -1;
  if (obj1.model > obj2.model) return 1;
  return 0;
}

function combineDuplicates(arr, comparator) {
  arr.sort(comparator);

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
    while (arr[i + 1] !== undefined && arr[i].model === arr[i + 1].model) {
      arr[i].quantity += arr[i + 1].quantity;
      arr.splice(i + 1, 1);
    }
  }

  return arr;
}
```

Basically, you sort the array and then loop through it. There is a second loop that keeps adding the quantities of duplicates and removing the duplicate afterwards. Not very efficient, but it works.

**Example**:

```
var product_array = [
    {model:1, quantity:3},
    {model:1, quantity:2},
    {model:2, quantity:1},
    {model:1, quantity:10},
    {model:1, quantity:10},
    {model:1, quantity:10},
    {model:2, quantity:5}
];

var new_product_array = combineDuplicates(product_array, comparator);
console.log(new_product_array); // [ { model: 1, quantity: 35 }, { model: 2, quantity: 6 } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this` in the `forEach` loop as a temporary object for merging.

```js
function removeDuplicates(input) {
    var new_array = [];
    input.forEach(function (unmerged) {
        if (!this[unmerged.model]) {
            this[unmerged.model] = unmerged;
            new_array.push(unmerged);
            return;
        }
        this[unmerged.model].quantity += unmerged.quantity;
    }, {});
    return new_array;
};

var product_array = [{ model: 1, quantity: 3 }, { model: 1, quantity: 2 }, { model: 2, quantity: 1 }],
    result = removeDuplicates(product_array);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```